# Apache 2.4 RewriteCond with expr / ipmatch on variable other than %{REMOTE_ADDR}

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a web server behind a CDN. The client IP is passed as an HTTP header.

I can use the following to block a client IP address:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CloudFront-Viewer-Address} ^123\.45\.67\.89(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

*I believe the `(.*)$` is required to match the port that may be included in `%{HTTP:CloudFront-Viewer-Address}`. I see the port (e.g. 127.0.0.1:1234) after `%{HTTP:CloudFront-Viewer-Address}` in access logs but not in rewrite logs. In rewrite logs, the port is appended to the CloudFront and load balancer addresses that precede the `%{HTTP:CloudFront-Viewer-Address}` but not the `%{HTTP:CloudFront-Viewer-Address}` itself.*

A CGI program prints something like:

```
HTTP_CLOUDFRONT_VIEWER_ADDRESS --> 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001:52325
HTTP_CLOUDFRONT_VIEWER_ADDRESS --> 127.0.0.1:45629
```

when I visit.

I'd like to use something like this:

```
RewriteCond expr "%{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch '123.45.67.0/24'"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

to block a range of IPs, as seen here: https://perishablepress.com/apache-redirect-range-ip-addresses/

but it doesn't work.

I tried:

```
RewriteCond expr "%{HTTP:CloudFront-Viewer-Address} -ipmatch '123.45.67.0/24'"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

I'm not sure if it's because `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` is the only variable ipmatch can work on; or the port that may be included in my variable; or some other reason.

Assuming it's the port, and ipmatch can act on `%{HTTP:CloudFront-Viewer-Address}`, might removing the port from `%{HTTP:CloudFront-Viewer-Address}` allow this to work?

I tried to do it using suggestions here: https://www.reddit.com/r/apache/comments/11bxlxi/cidr_matching_rewrite_with_expr_ipmatch_remove/ but couldn't get it working.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Where exactly are you using this rule? And what other directives do you have?

Comment: This rule and others are in a file called deny.conf that I'm including (via the Include directive) within several individual VirtualHost config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern I suggest here is to manipulate it up front with SetEnvIf and leave the result in an environment variable.

```
SetEnvIf CloudFront-Viewer-Address (.*):\d+$ cf-v-a=$1
RewriteCond expr "%{reqenv:cf-v-a} -ipmatch '123.45.67.0/24'"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: This seems to be working! Thank you so much. Looking back at the reddit thread it looks like the difference has to do with the reqenv('cf-v-a') syntax vs. %{ENV:cf-v-a}? Do I only need to do the SetEnvIf once; continuing with RewriteCond statements that can use %{ENV:cf-v-a}?

Comment: yeah the setenvif would just be once to set the var and then it's accessible to anythign that reads environment variables.    Sorry not sure where I picked up that env syntax, reqenv is probably clearer -- I will edit

Comment: I hadn't clicked through to reddit earlier, that's my answer there too!

Comment: Thanks. I verified the new syntax, it also seems to work (as %{ENV:cf-v-a} did). My point about the syntax is, with the example on Reddit, I recall it didn't seem to work for me - though this new syntax, %{reqenv:cf-v-a} is also different from the (non-working, for me) Reddit "reqenv('my-cf-address') ... example.

Comment: Is there any value to using SetEnvIfNoCase instead? It seems this manipulation should work on IPv6 addresses as well? I read IPv6 addresses are case-insensitive. Is there any chance IPv6 addresses might appear in different cases where SetEnvIfNoCase could help with this match? Or, would using [NC] in the RewriteCond also work? I wonder how either would affect IPv4 since those addresses are only numeric.

Comment: the syntax difference is using an expression as a string vs as a boolean. I don't think [NC] has any effect when using an expression in RewriteCone.  SetEnvIfNoCase can't help because the match is already not case sensitive.

Comment: very possible the answer on reddit never worked due to the wrong expression syntax